# How can we see the cookie set by the asp.net session?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, session-cookies

How can we see the cookie set by the asp.net in the browser? I see that the **`SET-COOKIE`** column in the chrome developer tools network-tab is always empty. Please refer the image below

[image]

I see the cookie value when i open the response's cookies tab as shown below in the image

[image]

If the cookie was not set for the first request of ASP.net page then from where is the cookie shown in the request as shown in the Response's Cookies tab?

Comment: Has that request set a cookie? does it appear in your resources / cookies tab? Note this column is just a count of the number of cookies set.

Comment: @TZHX added more info to the question

Comment: In the resources >> cookies you can see the asp.net session cookie.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why the vote down for this question?